# Why is my 2005 chevy impala engine knocking?

Tags: chevrolet

My 2005 chevy impala has been sitting since March. When i went to start it, it cranked up just fine. But when i rev on the gas i hear a ticking sound. It does it in park and drive. Thought it was oil, so put 4 quarts in. Still hear the ticking. It sounds perfectly normal until i hit the gas. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this sound appears all during cruise? Or does it end when engine warmed up?

Comment: are you saying it was so low on oil you needed to put 4 quarts in??? That kind of answers the question doesn't it? It only holds maybe 4 and a half..

Comment: Is it ticking or knocking, big difference.

Answer (score 1):

Could be that the lifters just bled down since it sat for so long.Make sure you have the proper amount of oil.  Start the engine, let idle until normal operating temperature is reached.  Raise the idle to about 1500rpm and hold for about 3mins. Let idle again and repeat if needed. You also may need to take it for a gentle drive once or twice.

Answer (score 0):

Could be piston slap. Some Chevy engines are notorious for the piston slap, which can appear even without any form of misuse such as running low on oil.

If this is piston slap, you have several options:

- Replace the bottom end of the engine. Usually not worth it unless you truly hate the sound.
- Demand the dealership to replace the engine bottom end that started piston slapping early. Trouble is, you cannot expect to succeed in this for over 10-year old car.
- Just continue driving the ticking car.
- Get rid of the car by selling it. Unfortunately, nobody wants a piston slapper so the amount of money you will be offered will be very, very low indeed considering the car is over 10 years old.
- Get rid of the car by scrapping it.
- (If you have enough land area) Buy a new(er) car and then you have two cars.

I would however say that if you added 4 quarts of oil, the engine is either over-filled now or alternatively was under-filled before you added the oil. Both of the options are bad. If it was under-filled, that can definitely cause piston slap.